# Circles and enneagon

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, polygons

[image: Question]

Using that in a triangle ABC, $\tan\frac A2=\frac{r}{p-a}$ where $p=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$, I found that the radius are equal if
$\tan^220°=\frac{\frac{1+2\cos40°}{\cos20°-1}}{1-\frac{1}{2\cos40°}+\frac{\sin60°}{\sin80°}}$
Can someone help me to prove this?
Thanks for antention!

Comment: Your first equation should be $\tan\frac{A}{2}=\frac{r}{p-a}$.

Comment: -@Cavalo, there might be an error in your calculations. [W|A](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%2B2%5Ccos+40°%7D%7B%5Ccos+20°-1%7D%7D%7B1-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%5Ccos+40°%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B%5Csin+60°%7D%7B%5Csin+80°%7D%7D) gives this result where RHS is negative but your LHS is always positive.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the annotated figure.

[image]

> **Claim 1**.  The intersecton of $A_1 A_6$ and $A_3 A_7$ at $O_2$ is also the incenter of $\triangle A_5 A_8 D$.

> **Proof**.  Let $O_2$ be the intersection of $A_1 A_6$ and $A_3 A_7$.  Note $\triangle A_6 A_7 O_2$ is equilateral.  Thus, $\triangle A_8 A_7 O_2$ is isosceles with $A_8 A_7 = O_2 A_7$.  Since $\angle A_8 A_7 O_2 = \frac{4\pi}{9}$, it follows that $$\angle A_7 A_8 O_2 = \angle A_8 O_2 A_7 = \frac{1}{2}\left(\pi - \frac{4\pi}{9}\right) = \frac{5\pi}{18}.$$  But since $\angle A_7 A_8 A_5 = \frac{2\pi}{9}$ and $\angle A_5 A_8 A_4 = \frac{\pi}{9}$, we have $$\angle M_2 A_8 O_2 = \angle A_7 A_8 O_2 - \angle A_7 A_8 A_5 = \frac{\pi}{18} = \frac{1}{2} \angle A_5 A_8 A_4.$$  Therefore, $A_8 O_2$ bisects $\angle D A_8 A_5$, and by symmetry, $A_5 O_2$ bisects $\angle D A_5 A_8$.  Consequently $O_2$ is also the incenter of $\triangle A_5 A_8 D$ as claimed.

As a result of this claim, we can easily calculate the inradius $r_2 = O_2 M_2$.  Without loss of generality let the side length of the $9$-gon be $1$, so in particular $A_6 A_7 = A_7 O_2 = A_7 A_8 = 1$.  Since $A_5 A_8 || A_6 A_7$ and $\angle A_7 A_8 A_5 = \frac{2\pi}{9}$, we have $PM_2 = \sin \frac{2\pi}{9}$, hence $$r_2 = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} - \sin \frac{2\pi}{9}.$$

Next, we proceed with calculating the inradius $r_1 = O_1 M_1$.  Note $\angle A_8 AB = \frac{\pi}{3}$ and $\angle A_1 A_8 M_1 = \frac{\pi}{9}$, hence $$AM_1 = r_1 \sqrt{3}, \quad M_1 A_8 = r_1 \cot \frac{\pi}{9},$$ so again assuming unit side length, we obtain $$r_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3} + \cot \frac{\pi}{9}}.$$  All that is left is to show $r_1 = r_2$; to this end, we consider the ratio
$$\begin{align}
\frac{r_2}{r_1} 
&= \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} - \sin \frac{2\pi}{9}\right)\left(\sqrt{3} + \cot \frac{\pi}{9}\right) \\
&= \left(\sin \frac{3\pi}{9} - \sin \frac{2\pi}{9}\right)\left(\tan \frac{3\pi}{9} + \cot \frac{\pi}{9}\right) \\
&= 2 \cos \frac{5\pi}{18} \sin \frac{\pi}{18} \left(\frac{\sin \frac{3\pi}{9} \sin \frac{\pi}{9} + \cos \frac{\pi}{9} \cos \frac{3\pi}{9}}{\cos \frac{3\pi}{9} \sin \frac{\pi}{9}} \right) \\
&= \sin \frac{2\pi}{9} \frac{\sin \frac{\pi}{9}}{\cos \frac{\pi}{18}} \frac{\cos \frac{2\pi}{9}}{\cos \frac{3\pi}{9} \sin \frac{\pi}{9}} \\
&= \frac{\sin \frac{2\pi}{9} \cos \frac{2\pi}{9}}{\frac{1}{2} \sin \frac{4\pi}{9}} \\
&= 1. 
\end{align}$$

I have no doubt there must be a more elegant way, possibly even a purely geometric one, but this was the most immediate approach that was sufficiently elementary that I could find.

---

**Edit.**

I have found an alternative solution.  Refer to the following figure.
[image]

> **Claim 2**.  The intersection $O_2$ of $A_1 A_6$ and $A_3 A_7$ is also the incenter of $\triangle A_1 A_5 A_7$.

> **Proof**.  $\angle A_1 A_7 A_3 = \angle A_3 A_7 A_5 = \frac{2\pi}{9}$, and $\angle A_7 A_1 A_6 = \angle A_6 A_1 A_5 = \frac{\pi}{9}$.

As a result of this claim, we conclude that the inradius $$r_3 = O_2 S = \sin \frac{2\pi}{9},$$ since $S$ is the midpoint of $O_2 A_8$ of isosceles $\triangle O_2 A_7 A_8$ and also the point of tangency of the corresponding incircle.

Next, note that $\triangle A_1 A_5 A_7 \sim \triangle A_8 A B$, simply by comparing their angle measures.  So $$r_1 = r_3 \frac{AA_8}{A_1 A_5} = 2\sin \frac{2\pi}{9} \sin \frac{\pi}{18}.$$  But we already established that $$r_2 = \sin \frac{3\pi}{9} - \sin \frac{2\pi}{9} = 2\cos \frac{5\pi}{18} \sin \frac{\pi}{18},$$ and since $\cos \frac{5\pi}{18} = \sin \frac{2\pi}{9}$, we are done.

Comment: Since the circles are tangent to the line $AA_5$, could you show that line is parallel to the line connecting the circle's centers? Then the two circles would have the same radius and be congruent.

Comment: @CSquared I had considered this approach but I could not find a simple way to demonstrate it.  The difficulty is that the location of $O_1$ is "inconvenient" in the sense that it is the incenter of a scalene triangle and does not lie on any axes of symmetry.

Comment: @heropup, nice explanation. Even I was trying since a week but didn't succeed.